# Xamarin Forms Language issues on Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, multilingual, resx

I'm going crazy for hours on an evil problem!!!

I've created a new Xamain Forms prj on Visual Studio for Mac (last version and last update).

I have three AppResources files for corrispondent languages:
 - AppResources.resx (for default)
 - AppResources.it.resx (for italian)
 - AppResources.es.resx (for spanish)

On IOS simulator, works all good. On Android I see always the default string.

This is my simple data on AppResources file:

```
AppResources.resx:
    <data name="test" xml:space="preserve">
        <value>Default</value>
    </data>

AppResources.es.resx:
        <data name="test" xml:space="preserve">
                <value>Espanol</value>
        </data>

AppResources.it.resx:
    <data name="test" xml:space="preserve">
            <value>Italiano</value>
    </data>
```

Why on IOS works perfectly and on Android I can see only "default"?!?

Comment: Have you followed this guide in order to make sure that everything is properly configured? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?pivots=windows. I have recently started a project with 6 languages in VS Mac and it works fine in iOS and Android. How do you initialise and update the culture you are using?

Comment: ummm this could be the problem....!!! 
"How do you initialise and update the culture you are using?" What do you mean?

Comment: But the code works on ios without any issue... why on android not?

Comment: On Android, the language settings are detected and cached when the application starts. If you change languages, you may need to exit and restart the application to see the changes applied.Check the tutorial:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?pivots=windows#test-localization

Comment: No... should be more easy, because I don't want to change language "live", I would like to see my application, at start, with correct language resources!!! But works only with IOS!

Comment: please clarify, changing the language does not work at all or only in release mode?, I have the same problem, but only in release mode, in debug mode everything works correctly

Comment: My problem is not during changing language... I have a simulator and physical device (both Android) one with spanish language and one with italian but I see always default appresources value. On ios all works better

Answer (score 2):

The problem started for me after the last visual studio (MAC) update (Version 8.6 (build 4520))

Look this:

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/4664#issuecomment-632986668

This workaround solved my problem.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it help you , which will help more people :)

Answer (score 0):

As a response to your comment above you could have a LocalizationService in which you will set and update your current culture (CultureInfo object). You can also use the static `CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture` to get the device culture.

```
    public CultureInfo CurrentCulture
    {
        get => cultureInfo;
        set
        {
            if(cultureInfo?.Equals(value) ?? false)
            {
                return;
            }
            cultureInfo = value;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = value;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using this:
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture;
as you say, It uses "it-IT" but the result does not change... it's possibile that the problem has caused from resources file that has "it" and the culture info instead is "it-IT"?

Comment: You shouldn' t have issues with that. For more info have a look at this https://csharp.net-tutorials.com/working-with-culture-and-regions/the-cultureinfo-class/. 
CurrentCulture property should be assigned with the culture your user might have selected or the one you explicitly want to force. I would suggest keeping a collection of the cultures you support (english, italian, spanish) and assign them to your CultureInfo object based on your app's logic.

Comment: No trust me... same code same configuration: on ios works on android it doesn't!

Comment: Maybe a matter of different culture returned in iOS device and Android? As a workaround you could just get the TwoLetterISOLanguageName from the device culture and use that to compare and assign a CultureInfo object to CurrentCulture

Comment: I've tried with this:
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName);

but fails... I'm very nervous... :/

Comment: The other option is to try setting the culture whenever an activity is resumed. Inside the OnResume method Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture

Comment: The strange thing is that if I use a brekpoint to AppResources.Culture It visualize "it". It's like Android not found the resources localized file.... but it's and embeddedresource!!!

Comment: If you are testing on an emulator I would suggest trying also on a physical device. Also try also setting Appresources.Culture when you update your Culture.

Comment: I’m testing in both devise: simulator and physical but the result does not change